# Why is unity not modifying my player's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, topdown

I'm making a 2D top-down game, and I'm currently trying to implement a checkpoint system. The checkpoint saves the scene the player was in correctly, and it saves the player's X and Y coordinates. However, when respawning, the player does not go to the right location and instead goes to the spawnpoint of the scene. It may be a simple fix, as I am relatively new to game design, but I've been stuck on this for at least a month now.

I have tried a number of ways to get the player to read the saved locations.
The checkpoint location saves correctly in PlayerPrefs, and I have tested it multiple times proving that the values save.

This is my respawn function:

```
public void Respawn()
{
    string lastLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savedScene");
    lastCheckPointPos.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("savedX");
    lastCheckPointPos.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("savedY");
    player.transform.position = new Vector3(lastCheckPointPos.x, lastCheckPointPos.y, 0);
    print("respawing");
    SceneManager.LoadScene(lastLevel);
}
```

At first I tried setting the player's individual X and Y values to the saved ones in separate lines of code, setting player.transform.x to savedX and so on, but this did not work. I searched around online and saw that it should work if I put it as a new Vector3, which made sense, but this did not work either. *Again, the problem is NOT with saving to PlayerPrefs, the player just cannot seem to read the variables.*

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated as this is the last big roadblock holding me back from continuing progression on the game.

Comment: depends what you're looking at but if player is part of the scene, its being reloaded..

Comment: @BugFinder yes, but I'm using playerprefs which (to my knowledge) saves across scenes.

Comment: When you debug, what is the content of PlayerPrefs?? Also, try to replace the PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("savedX") and PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("savedY") by hardcoded values and see what happens in the game

Comment: @jarmanso7 Hm, I replaced them with hardcoded values and it still did nothing. The "player.transform.position = etc etc etc" line just seems to do nothing. I have lines of code printing the PlayerPrefs savedX and savedY variables as well as the lastCheckPointPos variable. They all save properly and it seems to be the single line of code that isn't right.

Comment: If the results of this little experiment are that replacing those variables by hardcoded values bear no change at all, then I'm guessing that the problem isn't with saving to PlayerPrefs as you said. Anyway, why did you dismissed my first question? Did you actually try to debug and see the values? does the debugger actually breaks if you put a breakpoint in that line, or not? I am not familiar with unity, can you use breakpoints, or are you limited to print values for debugging?

Comment: @jarmanso7 sorry, I'm relatively new to this so I don't quite understand what you mean by trying to debug (or what breakpoints are for that matter)

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in a line of code and run an application in debug mode, the execution will "stop" at that particular line of code and let you examine in detail the status of memory, variable values, calls etc.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I see. To my knowledge, Unity does not have that (again I am new so who knows), so the only way I can debug test the values is with print functions.

Comment: I see, I don't know about Unity I'm sorry.

Comment: if you have different player gameobjects in different scenes then you're setting position of player gameobject in old scene. Let's say this script you have is in Scene_1, in "SceneManager.LoadScene(lastLevel);"  part, you load Scene_2. In this case Player gameobject in Scene_1 will be destroyed as Scene_1 will be unloaded and Scene_2 will be loaded. So you need to set the position of new player gameobject in the loaded scene in this case Scene_2. Same thing applied for reloading same scene.

Comment: However @pawzypuppy  as this is just a few lines of code it does indeed depend when you read the values back from playerprefs youve not shown that

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggesting/helping, I've found a solution on another site, it checks if the player just loaded from a save every time the start function is called, and if it did, it sets the player to the checkpoint location.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you do     SceneManager.LoadScene(lastLevel) Your scene / values reset to their original value, there is no sense in reloading the scene after reading values because they will just be reset.

The way to do it would be to load the scene first then load the settings/positioning

Comment: Appreciate the answer, I have found a solution very similar to this on another site. Thank you